# "Dire avoir connu"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, infinitif, temps-composés

Trying to figure out if this is a fixed phrase, or a grammatical construction I'm just unfamiliar with. It's from a children's version of *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*. See the bolded portion:

> Certains vieux pêcheurs **disent l'avoir connue.**

I understand this as *Certain old fishermen say they knew her*, but the grammar confuses me. I would have thought it would be this:

> Certains vieux pêcheurs disent qu'ils l'ont connue.

Can I get an explanation of the grammar in the first sentence, and also some insight as to why my version is wrong or not well-phrased?

Comment: The same construciton appears again later in the paragraph, btw: *Certains d'entre eux disent même l'avoir vu partir de Marseille vers Aix-en-Provence sur un cheval noir.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ils disent l'avoir connue.

and

> Ils disent qu'ils l'ont connue.

mean exactly the same thing, but the first sentence is less frequent in spoken French. A similar construction (verbe + infinitif) can be found in:

> Il prétend être notre ami. (Il prétend qu'il est notre ami)
>
> J'aimerais avoir à nouveau vingt ans. (J'aimerais que j'aie à nouveau vingt ans)

In this last example the verbe + infinitif form is more used because the repetition of "je" makes the sentence clumsy.

Comment: You say the second one is more common, John says the second one is "rather cumbersome." Who do I believe??

Comment: The second one is more common, among real people who are not French teachers and grammar specialists. I think both John and me are right here :)

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct and equivalent.

A verb directly following another verb is generally (always?) at the infinitive (first case.)

The verb located in a *proposition subordonnée* is conjugated (second case.)

Comment: Yes, I know one verb following another is usually (always?) infinitive, but it's the implied *that* which throws me here, since out of habit I've learned to read the infinitive as an implied *to*. So I read this literally as "Certain old fishermen say to have known her," when it ought to be "Certain old fishermen say that they knew her."

Answer (score 1):

**Les deux formes sont équivalentes. Il n'y en a pas une de vraiment plus utilisée que l'autre.**

La forme avec la relative *que ...* est un peu plus lourde (mais plus facile à construire car générique), elle ne profite pas de la forme allégée avec l'infinitif:

Les verbes d'**affirmation, de sensation** peuvent en général utilise cette tournure avec un infinitif, qui évite de répéter le **sujet** quand il est **le même** que celui de la **principale**. Il est même *déconseillé* d'utiliser la tournure relative dans ces cas-là :

> Je dis l'avoir connue = Je dis que je l'ai connue.
>
> J'affirme ...
>
> Je confirme ...
>
> J'avoue ...
>
> Je confesse ...
>
> Je pense manger ...
>
> J'imagine ...
>
> Je crois détenir un secret.

Answer (score 0):

For me, those two versions are exactly the same, put apart the wording of the second one is rather cumbersome...
So you can use :

- dire + avoir/être + participe passé + complément (COD, CC de lieux, de temps,...)
- dire + pronom + avoir/être + participe passé (if the complement has already be defined in the sentence)
- dire + QUE + avoir/être CONJUGUÉS + participe passé
- dire + QUE + pronom + avoir/être CONJUGUÉS + participe passé (if the complement has already be defined in the sentence).

I hope I have not forgotten any case !

Comment: You say the first one is more elegant, Anne says the first one is less frequently used. Who do I believe??

Comment: In fact we mean the same thing : the first one is more formal, so less used !

Comment: Les formes 2 et 3 (sans exemple fourni) sont normalement grammaticalement impossibles. -1 . Les formes 1 et 4 sont justement les 2 formes de la question (infinitif / relative)